# Package chromedriver is not available, but is referred to by another package

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to install chromedriver.

I was trying on a virtual box. Then I switched to my actual box but got the same problem:

```
$ sudo apt install chromedriver
[sudo] password for michael: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package chromedriver is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'chromedriver' has no installation candidate
```